# How to align the text inside the android text view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

For example, I have a ListView , and for each row that data is like this

```
Name: Mr.ABC
Address: Flat A, 25/F, Block 2, 
USA....
Gender: Male
Hobbies: Football, Baseball.....
.....
```

And the above is how it currently look likes, I use 4 text view to represent each data

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultLang"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultOrg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is how can I align the text like this?

```
Name:    Mr.ABC
Address: Flat A, 25/F, Block 2, 
         USA....
Gender:  Male
Hobbies: Football, Baseball.....
         .....
```

Thanks for helping

Updated

```
  <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/search_name"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultName"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/search_lang"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultLang"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/search_type"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultType"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/search_org"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultOrg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/search_yr"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultYear"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The above is updated code but the problem is , since it is listview and I found that the left side width is not equal . It is something like e.g.

```
Name:    Mr.ABC
Address: Flat A, 25/F, Block 2, 
         USA....
Gender:  Male
Hobbies: Football, Baseball.....
         .....

Name:        Mr.Asfsafasfdfsd
Address:     Flat V, 25/F, Block 2, 
             USA....
Gender:      Female
Hobbies:     Basketball.....
             .....

Name:      Mr.WQWRWEE
Address:   Flat V, 25/F, Block 2, 
           USA....
Gender:    Male
Hobbies:   Baseball.....
           .....
```

Comment: You could use 8 textviews. I don't think you could get desired alignment using just 4 textviews

Comment: yes and using weight layout, but how can I define the weight? thanks

Comment: e.g. 1 for the name: and 9 for the Mr. ABC? but what if a device screen is too small to show the name?

Comment: Umm..sorry, I didn't think this through. Given that you need alignment both in horizontal and vertical direction, it might be better to use TableLayout as pointed out by Raghu

Comment: Would you mind to take a look in updated question? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNameLable"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Name : "/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNameValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Mr.ABC"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddressLable"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Address : "/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddressValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Flat A, 25/F, Block 2,\nUSA...."/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGenderLable"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Gender : "/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGenderValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Male"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHobbiesLable"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Hobbies : "/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHobbiesValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Football,Baseball \n......"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @user782104: Can you please let us know if this works? I think it should but I am curious how it turned out for with varying text lengths. I guess, you can always adjust the weights to come up with optimal values.

Comment: sure, but is it work for all device in different resolution? e.g. 0.75 is for xxhdpi but 0.5 for hdpi etc...

Comment: work as expected but I believe the weight need to be change if the locale is differenet

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want is a Table that contains rows with two columns. I am guessing, you should use the TableLayout to lay out the twi TextViews.

Good Luck